# 64 bit Migration of Carbon APIs

Tags: macos, 32bit-64bit, macos-carbon

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/115932 like this post I also need to use carbon in my mac app but, what I know carbon api only support 32 bit OS & from Mac OS 10.15 onwards it won't support 32 bit apps. So I won't be able to use Carbon API.

[No Carbon Human-Interface-Toolbox in OSX 64-bit binaries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2849320/no-carbon-human-interface-toolbox-in-osx-64-bit-binaries) - I gone through this post but could not understand much actually what I need to do.

Below is my current code. What will be replacement or migration of this Carbon API, what is the correct alternative?

```
static const EventTypeSpec menuEnableEvents[] =
    {
        { kEventClassMenu, kEventMenuEnableItems }
    };

    static const EventTypeSpec menuEvents[] =
    {
        { kEventClassCommand, kEventCommandProcess }
    };
```

Comment: Please explain what the context of the code in your question is. What sort of event handler are you setting up here?

Comment: Apple header File: HIToolbox/CarbonEvents.h says : 
1. kEventClassMenu  - Events related to menus.
2. enum {
  kEventMenuEnableItems         = 8
};

3. /*
   * Events related to commands generated by menu items or controls.
   * These events contain HICommand structures.
   */
  kEventClassCommand            = 'cmds',

enum {
  kEventCommandProcess          = 1
};

Comment: …right, but what are you using these event handlers for? Or is this just boilerplate?

Comment: I am also not sure about the use of it, since I recently started on this code base, which was written 15 years back with no documentation. I know I need to replace the Carbon APIs to corresponding Cocoa APIs

Comment: You need to understand your code first. There's no way to blindly replace Carbon APIs with something more modern without understanding what the code is for and what it is doing.